# regex working in Patterns App and Oyster but not in terminal

Tags: regex, curl, terminal

I'm trying to extract the link in-between the two quotes after the "upload_link_secure":

I came up with this regex that works in all the regex apps (Patterns, Oyster) but every time I run it in the terminal I get **grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced**. I've tried grep -e grep -E grep -P. Nothing is working.

```
((?<=\"upload_link_secure\":\s\")([^\"]*))
```

I'm kinda lost now...

```
[...]
         "upload_link_secure": "https://12345.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=1a2a3a4a5a&video_file_id=12345&signature=71a2a3a4a5a&v6=1&full_hd=0&redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Fupload%2Fapi%3Fvideo_file_id%3D12345%26app_id%3D12345%26ticket_id%3D1a2a3a4a5a%26signature%3D1a2a3a4a5a",
[...]
```

At the end of the day I'm doing a POST curl, getting the data, and now I want to parse the data to reuse in a separate curl POST.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include  the pattern within `()`.

```
command | grep -oP '\"upload_link_secure\"\s*:\s*\"\K[^\"]*'
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful with an explanation of the change you've made to the pattern, such as the fact that the `\K` pattern instructs the regex engine to match what precedes it but to discard everything that precedes it from the result.